# Align Theorem With Bullet Itemize

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize, amsthm

I am trying to get the **Theorem.** to line up with the bullet. I tried using `\vspace{-\topsep}`, but this moves the bullet up along with the **Theorem.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{theorem}
        $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
    \end{theorem}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: theorems are numbered structural displayed paragraphs  butting it in an itemize is rather strange (and probably none of the theorem packages has ever been tested for such a usage, so you'd just have to patch as needed)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately our problem set formatting requirements demand that it be placed in a list (hence the strange usage). thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means but I guess if you have to you have to. If you just want a bullet to the left of the theorem head you could define the theorem environment that way, does it really have to be in an itemize??? Anyway if you do want that I would probably use `\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{theorem...` possibly with \ vspace correction inside the box to get whatever you need.

Comment: If you want to place a bullet before the theorem, why do not use `\newtheorem{theorem}{$\bullet$ Theorem}` instead of using `itemize`?

Comment: @Cragfelt Many of the questions have subparts and I figured it would be easier than manually doing all the indentation.

Comment: I thought exactly the same as @DavidCarlisle, but used a [c] for the minipage in my example (Of course I let it in user and could give an initial value too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a theorem has a list structure, you just have to compensate for the corresponding vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \leavevmode\vspace{-\dimexpr \baselineskip + \topsep}\begin{theorem}
        $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Some text some text some text. Some text some text some text. Some text some text some text. Some text some text some text.
    \end{theorem}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{ittheorem}[1][t]{\begin{minipage}[#1]{0.1\textwidth}\begin{itemize}\item \end{itemize}\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.88\textwidth}\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item
\begin{theorem}
        $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
    \end{theorem}
\end{itemize}

\begin{ittheorem}[t]
  $a^2+b^2=c^2$
  you can include some text and whatever accepted in a real theorem environment
\end{ittheorem}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi. In your code I have seen that there is a [c] that it is visible in theorem 2. There are also the typo in the text (you can see "soome" and "theotem").

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano

Comment: It is for me a pleasure to help a my friend :-) and the new users :-)))))) I have upvoted yesterday :-)