# Theorems in itemize/enumerate do not align with bullets

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize, amsthm, thmtools

I am starting off enumerate bullets with some custom theorem environments using `amsthm` and `thmtools`. Here is the misaligned example along with the code.

Notice how the "proof" environment provided by `amsthm` works perfectly (why?). Also, notice that the custom `amsthm` "theorem" environment doesn't align at first, but aligns perfectly after applying the standard fix described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411806/230326). Lastly, observe that the custom `thmtools` "counterexample" environment also doesn't align, even after applying the above fix (the spacing is somehow different).

Is this expected behavior? If so, I would like to know why this is the behavior between these environments and enumerate. If not, what would you recommend going forward? Also, why does the "proof" environment work perfectly?

[image: example with the alignment issue]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}

\newtheoremstyle{thmstyle}
{}{}%
{}{}%
{\bfseries}{.}%
{1em}%
{\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\newtheorem*{thm}{}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    headpunct={.},
    postheadspace=1em,
    qed=\qedsymbol,
    numbered=no,
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, name=Counterexample]{counterexample}


\newcommand{\modulo}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    % uncomment below to fix
    \item % \leavevmode\vspace{-\dimexpr \baselineskip + \topsep}
          \begin{thm}[Theorem]
              Prove or disprove that if $a^2 \equiv b^2 \modulo m$, then
              $a \equiv b$ or $-b \modulo m$.
          \end{thm}

    % the above fix doesn't quite work here
    \item \begin{counterexample}
              some text

              some text
          \end{counterexample}

    \item \begin{proof}
              some text

              some text
          \end{proof}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's hard to say if it's expected behaviour as it's not really expected input to have theorems in a list, so some kind of vertical adjustment is likely or (perhaps more naturally) remove the itemize, and if you want a bullet as part of the theorem heading specify that in a custom theorem style.

Comment: unrelated but there is a standard `\pmod` command to do (mod 5)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestions! I'll consider not using theorems then if this isn't their use case. I also knew about `\pmod`, but I didn't really like the wide spacing so I decided to roll my own.

Comment: The compensation works if you use [spaceabove=\topsep,] in mystyle.  (Alas, spaceabove=-\baselineskip does not work).